# Does Quark know that the "captain" is a member of the Q?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-q, ferengi, quark

In "Q-Less," Q arrives on Deep Space Nine to try to persuade Vash to continue exploring the universe with him. Early in the episode, Q makes Quark disappear after the latter had the audacity to ring Vash's doorbell and try to enter her quarters. Later, while at the auction, Q speaks of the impending doom of the station and bids enormous amounts of latinum.

Of course, Q is in a captain's uniform at the time.

I take statements to be true (unless there is good reason to doubt them), so Q's later statement to Captain Janeway about impressing females of every species is canon, as far as I'm concerned. Thus, this would also include the Ferengi. However, this does not mean Quark personally has knowledge of the Q.

Is there anything in Star Trek (preferably canon, but EU as well), that speaks to how much (if anything) Quark knows about the Q, and also what the Ferengi was thinking when dealing with this "captain" during the events of "Q-Less"?

Comment: "I take statements to be true" you mean you would trust the word of a Q?

Comment: Captain Janeway seemed to.

Comment: Quark is a Q.   That's why his name starts with Q.   This question is nonsense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Main canon - We don't know.

It's not entirely clear *what* Quark knows about Q, other than that he clearly takes the million bar bid totally at face value, suggesting that he's at least aware that Q is no mere penniless Starfleet Captain.

> **Q:** [Bids] *A million.*
>
> Quark can die happy now.
>
> **QUARK:** *A million bars of gold press latinum.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Q-Less: Original Screenplay](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/407.txt)</sup></sub>

Quark has, thus far in the episode seen Q twice before. Once in Vash's quarters when he was transported away (and returned confused)

> **VASH:** *I don't know.  You didn't give him time to tell me.  Now bring him back   this instant.*
>
> **Q:** *Oh, very well.*
>
> Quark REAPPEARS.  Vash looks around and Q is gone. (Lose one Q FLASH.)
>
> **ANGLE ON QUARK
>
>   a picture of confusion.**

And then again in the fantasy boxing ring, which he may or may not remember after Q sent everyone back to where they came from.

**On neither occasion do we get any indication what he does or doesn't know.**

---

### EU - He knows exactly who and what Q is.

Within the EU novels the answer is rather more simple. Quark, a man who makes it his business to know things about things (following [Rule of Acquisition #194](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Rules_of_Acquisition)) has been asking around about Q. Not only has he gained a broad understanding of Q's powers and capabilities, he's also shared a photograph of him with the entire Ferengi nation along with a dire warning to steer a very wide path if he's encountered. In the scene below, Nagus Zek is speaking with Q.

> *Picard shrugged.*
>   *I* *turned back to the Ferengi. “Have we met?” I asked.
>   “No! But...but Quark...he circulated a picture of you to all Ferengi after you appeared at Deep Space 9! He said you were the most dangerous being in the entire cosmos!”
>
>   His whining was becoming quite grating, but I rather enjoyed his terror. “Ah, flattery,” I sighed. “You’d be amazed how far that gets you.” 
>   He was now on his knees begging. It was a sight to see. “Look...I’m sure we can work something out...you can take half my earnings...no...no, take all of them...in fact, you can have the whole business...just don’t kill me with one of your thoughts. Quark said you could—”*
>
> <sub><sup>[I, Q](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/I,_Q)</sup></sub>

Comment: EU canon: Ah, but did Quark know those things *before* or *after* the events of "Q-Less"?

Comment: I have that book, but I haven’t read it in years. Thanks, Valorum.

Comment: @Kevin - Good question. Dunno.